# Kotlin ChatApp doesnt show messages

Tags: firebase, kotlin, crash, chat

I simply followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Pv96bvBJL4&ab_channel=GeeksforGeeks

Untill the end it was working fine. At the end, chat application started to crash when you try to text someone. [I simply added push() method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqHJK.png)

Now it stopped crashing but I am not able to see the messages. Firebase`s database is perfectly fine but I couldnt make it seen in the app. Sorry for the inexperience. I am new in Kotlin and this is the first time I am a asking a question. Thanks for all of the support.

Here is the code of Chat Activity (In my opinion messageList never adds a thing.. So messages arent showed in the app. But added to database perfectly):

```
package com.biointel.biointelchatapplication

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var chatRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var  messageBox: EditText
    private lateinit var sendButton: ImageView
    private lateinit var messageAdapter: MessageAdapter
    private lateinit var messageList: ArrayList<Message>
    private lateinit var mDbRef: DatabaseReference

    var receiverRoom: String? = null
    var senderRoom: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)


        val name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        val receiverUid = intent.getStringExtra("uid")

        val senderUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
        mDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

        senderRoom = receiverUid + senderUid
        receiverRoom = senderUid + receiverUid

        supportActionBar?.title = name

        chatRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatRecyclerView)
        messageBox = findViewById(R.id.messageBox)
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sentButton)
        messageList = ArrayList()
        messageAdapter = MessageAdapter(this,messageList)

        chatRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        chatRecyclerView.adapter = messageAdapter


        // Logic for adding to recyclerView
        mDbRef.child("chats").child(senderRoom!!).child("messages").push()
            .addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                    //messageList.clear()

                    for(postSnapshot in snapshot.children){

                        val message = postSnapshot.getValue(Message::class.java)
                        messageList.add(message!!)
                    }
                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }

            })

        sendButton.setOnClickListener{

            // adding the message to database

            val message = messageBox.text.toString()
            val messageObject = Message(message, senderUid)

            mDbRef.child("chats").child(senderRoom!!).child("messages")
                .setValue(messageObject).addOnSuccessListener {
                    mDbRef.child("chats").child(receiverRoom!!).child("messages")
                        .setValue(messageObject)
                }
            messageBox.setText("")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a crash report?

Comment: By crash, I meant app stop running and close itself. I runned debugger and no errorres.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image. Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Messages are recorded to database but never seen in the app